# Sum of Multiple Series

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

I don't know how to solve this series summation question. I tried breaking it down, but I'm just kind of lost how to manipulate it to give me the value.

$$f(n,k) = \sum\limits_{s=0}^n\sum\limits_{r=s}^n\sum\limits_{t=0}^s\frac{\binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{s}\binom{s}{t}t(3k^2)^{t/2}I(t)}{s+1}$$

where $I(t) = \begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\equiv 0\pmod{4}\\0&\text{if }x\equiv 1\pmod{4}\\-1&\text{if }x\equiv 2\pmod{4}\\0&\text{if }x\equiv 3\pmod{4}\end{cases}$

The variables (*N*) and (*K*) are given to me. However, I want to print the answer modulo `10^9+21`. If the answer ends up being P/Q, then print the answer `PQ^-1 (mod 10^9+21)`.

I understand that we're using Binomial Coefficient and that's:

`(n k) = [n! / k! * (n - k)!]`

and that I can simplify the last part of the formula from (3k^2)^t/2 to be:

`t * (3k) ^ t`

also, that, I(t) is just `I^t = sqrt(-1)`

Examples,

> f(1, 2) = 0

> f(2, 1) = 1000000019

> f(5, 3) = 4464

> f(3, 1) = -33/2

How,

```
 I guess you need to work in modulo arithmetic - for that particular example:
 
 Ex: 
 f(3, 1) = [3 = N, 1 = K]

 => x/y = x * y^-1

 => -33 = 1000000021 - 33 = 999999988

 => 2 ^ -1 = 500000011 

 => 500000011 * 2 = 1000000022 = 1000000021 + 1 = 1

 => 999999988 * 500000011 = 500000004999999868 = 

 => 499999994 * 1000000021 + 499999994 = 499999994
```

Hence the answer of the example *f(3, 1)* in modulo arithmetic is *499999994*

*No clue how the answer is coming out to be that.*

I want to be able to program this question, but I want to understand the math behind it before I *attempt* to program this.

Comment: So, the exact example you ask about is highly tedious and complicated and it would not be so helpful to talk about that example exactly.  What aspect of it specifically are you not understanding?  The fact that there are multiple nested summations?

Comment: Well, the entire summations part and the last part of the function. I'm assuming a lot of manipulation is happening between, s = 0, s = n, r = s, r = n, t = 0, t = s? If that's correct, then I understand what's happening between the summation series, but I don't understand the binomial part and the entirety of the second portion of the function.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of a query that you recently posted that you subsequently deleted?  It looks very familiar.  I looked at this recently, for about 30 minutes, and couldn't solve it.  If it helps, $I(t)$ is simply the **real** part of $i^t$, where $i = \sqrt{-1}.$  Assuming that it wasn't you that posted this, then someone else did.  I distinctly remember wrestling with $I(t)$ and then trying to move forward.

Comment: Query? As far as I remember, this is my first time posting on Stack Exchange. Oh, that helps, awesome! Yeah, but this is my first time posting this question. Maybe, you saw something similar, who knows? Yeah, I'm completely baffled at this question. I tried to break this question down from each separate part and don't understand it.

Comment: Rereading your question, I notice something off.  You wrote somewhere $(3k^2)^{t/2}$ can be simplified to $(3k)^t$.  This is incorrect.  You forgot to alter the $3$ which was in the parentheses as well.  Do not confuse $(3k)^2$ with $3(k^2)$.  If you insisted on it, you would have had $(3k^2)^{t/2} = (k\cdot \sqrt{3})^t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nested summations, you can choose to evaluate the inner summation before the outer summation if you are able to algebraically manipulate things.  Since you are not and you want to program this, it is easier instead perhaps to iterate over the sum of sums, making splitting it into several separate summations to add together.

For instance:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^3\sum\limits_{j=1}^i i\cdot j = \sum\limits_{j=1}^1 1\cdot j + \sum\limits_{j=1}^2 2\cdot j + \sum\limits_{j=1}^3 3\cdot j$$

$$=1\cdot (1) + 2\cdot (1+2) + 3\cdot (1+2+3) = 23$$

Alternatively $\sum\limits_{i=1}^3\sum\limits_{j=1}^i i\cdot j = \sum\limits_{i=1}^3 i\cdot i(i+1)/2 = \dots$

As far as pseudocode, this is just nested `for` loops.  You have something like:

```
runningtotal = 0
for i ranging from 1 to 3 {
    for j ranging from 1 to i {
        runningtotal += i * j
    }
}
```

modified for whatever language you are specifically using for the format.

As far as taking $I$ into account, to read this in pseudocode, it may be best to think of this as a switch statement.

```
I = function(x) {
    switch (x%4) {
        case 0:
             return 1
             break
        case 2:
             return -1
             break
        default:
             return 0
             break
      }
 }
```

That is, if $x$ is a multiple of $4$, $I$ will give a value of $1$, else if $x$ is a multiple of $2$ which is not a multiple of $4$, then $I$ will give a value of $-1$.  Finally, if $x$ is odd it will give a value of $0$.

As for using this inside of the loop... just define your function/method $I$ before running the loop and have $I$ appear inside of the expression that is added to the runningtotal.

For further example including $I$, this becomes:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^3\sum\limits_{j=1}^i I(i\cdot j) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^1 I(1\cdot j) + \sum\limits_{j=1}^2 I(2\cdot j) + \sum\limits_{j=1}^3 I(3\cdot j)$$

$$=I(1\cdot 1) + I(2\cdot 1) + I(2\cdot 2) + I(3\cdot 1)+I(3\cdot 2)+I(3\cdot 3)$$

$$=I(1)+I(2)+I(4)+I(3)+I(6)+I(9) = 0+(-1)+1+0+(-1)+0 = -1$$

Comment: You have three nested `for` loops, the outer of which uses $s$ as the indexing variable and ranges from $0$ to $n$, the second of which uses $r$ as the indexing variable and ranges from $s$ to $n$, and the innermost of which uses $t$ as the indexing variable and ranges from $0$ to $s$, exactly how it appears when writing it on paper.  As for how to work with the pieces in the summand... they just appear as part of the summand... what you're adding to `runningtotal` at the line(s) of code inside the innermost loop.

Comment: As for $(3k)^{t/2}$ specifically... you should note that since $I(t)=0$ whenever $t$ is odd, you will necessarily have $t/2$ is an integer in any case where the expression as a whole is nonzero, so you don't have to worry so much about irrational numbers creeping into your summation.